# Wordpress the author function waterfall page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a custom blog roll for my website but cannot for the life of me figure out how to print out the author. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="blog_roll">
<?
  $args = array('tag__not_in' => '5');
  $posts = get_posts($args);
  foreach($posts as $post) {
?>
    <div class="waterfall"> 
        <div id="waterfall_thumb">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="waterfall_title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="waterfall_author">
            by:<?php the_author();?>on <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?>
        </div>  
        <div id="waterfall_exc">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_excerpt ); ?></div>    
        </div>
    <? } ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `the_author()` function works only inside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)™. To get an author's details outside the Loop, you can take the author's ID from the `$post` object and use it with the `the_author_meta()` function:

```
… by: <?php the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author); ?> …
```

See the [function reference in the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) for other available fields.

By the way, `the_permalink` also works only inside the Loop. You need to use

```
<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this on my wordpress blog

```
$user_url = get_the_author_meta('user_url', $post->post_author);
$user_name = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $post->post_author);
echo '<a href="' . $user_url . '" rel="author">' . ' by ' . $user_name . '</a>';
```

As the other user mentions, the_author is only available inside the loop, so you need to use the_author_metadata (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta)